# Will setDefaultRequestConfig method override system properties - CloseableHttpClient

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using the following code to make a Http request.

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(10000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000)
                .setSocketTimeout(300000)
                .build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
```

My simple question, will the method `setDefaultRequestConfig` remove all the system properties and will keep only the properties given above OR will it override only the given properties and keep the other system properties while making the HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

System properties that HttpClientBuilder can optionally take into consideration are as follows

- ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm
- javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType
- javax.net.ssl.trustStore
- javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider
- javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
- ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm
- javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType
- javax.net.ssl.keyStore
- javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider
- javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
- https.protocols
- https.cipherSuites
- http.proxyHost
- http.proxyPort
- http.nonProxyHosts
- http.keepAlive
- http.maxConnections
- http.agent

Request level configuration have no effect on any of those settings with an exception of proxy host and port. Proxy setting at the request level will override those at the system level.